# Values of timestamp in Linux

Tags: linux, timestamp

Using `date +%s` i have checked timestamps of my system `1373977364`.

Is there any command i could reverse to check with `1373977364` to get initial value .

I also used this command `date -d @$1373976832` but its giving 1981 date , but this time stamp is of current time. So can any one guide me.

And i also like to know that I have log file and i like to check first and last interval in it . so i can know the exact time interval. So any one can guide me with this.

Log file has 
time stamp

```
1255478541
1245875645
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dollar sign in your command is causing unexpected results.

```
$ date -d @$1373976832 
Sat Nov  7 10:27:12 GMT 1981
$ date -d @1373976832 
Tue Jul 16 12:13:52 GMT 2013
```

In order to find the difference between two timestamp in days, you can say:

```
$ echo "(1255478541-1245875645)/3600" | bc
2667
```

Comment: to get days instead of hours:  `echo $(( (1255478541 - 1245875645) / (3600 * 24) ))`